# Unable to execute command: MySQL

Tags: mysql

```
create table `payrollmanagementsystem`.DEDUCTION
(
    CODE VARCHAR(50) not null primary key,
    NAME VARCHAR(50),
    SALARYPERDAY DOUBLE PRECISION,
    LEAVE INT,
    KWSP DOUBLE PRECISION,
    TOTALDEDUCTION DOUBLE PRECISION
)
```

I had face the problem with unable to execute command as error below:

```
Unable to execute command:
create table `payrollmanagementsystem`.DEDUCTION
(
    CODE VARCHAR(50) not null primary key,
    NAME VARCHAR(50),
    SALARYPERDAY DOUBLE PRECISION,
    LEAVE INT,
    KWSP DOUBLE PRECISION,
    TOTALDEDUCTION DOUBLE PRECISION
)
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LEAVE INT,
    KWSP DOUBLE PRECISION,
    TOTALDEDUCTION DOUBLE PRECISION
)' at line 6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others pointed out, LEAVE is a keyword. To solve your problem, use backticks:

```
`LEAVE` INT,
```

Be aware that **CODE** is a keyword as well, though in this case it won't cause a problem. It's still good practice to escape your column names.

Answer (score 0):

Because of this:
[LEAVE - keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/leave.html)